# SQL Server DTS/SSIS decimals dot instead of comma

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

A view is exported weekly by a job, into a text file, using a DTS package. I created the DTS package using the Import Export Wizard.
The decimal separator in the output file is a comma (,).
How can I make it a dot (.) ?

---

I tried changing the LocaleId property of the Dataflow box to English (United States), with no result.
I tried the same on destination table's LocalId property, no result.
What else, George ??

Comment: you can use the "Write a query to specify the data to transfer" in the "Specify Table Copy or Query" Section of the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard" before saving the package.

Comment: @ughai Thx for the info. I did write the query before using the wizard. Perhaps having teh query in the wizard makes it easier to maintain ?

Comment: the query should help you if there is other code accessing your view. you can change your query later in the the package rather than changing the definition of your view

Comment: Maybe convert the column to a varchar and replace the comma with a dot?

Comment: @TabAlleman: that's the solution. Could you put that in an answer so I mark is as answered ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the column to a varchar, making it locale-agnostic, and use string functions to replace the comma with a dot.